# RichFaces: Clear required fields when clicking cancel button

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, richfaces

Lets say I have three inputs in a modal dialog panel:

**Field A:**

```
<h:inputText id="fieldA" value="#{callbackDialog.fieldA}" required="true">
```

**Field B:**

```
<h:inputTextarea id="fieldB" value="#{callbackDialog.fieldB}" required="false" rows="4" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.substring(0, 255);"/>
```

**Field C:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="fieldC" value="#{callbackDialog.fieldC}" required="true">
    <s:selectItems value="#{callbackDialog.fieldCList}"
        var="fieldC" 
        label="#{fieldC.name}"
        hideNoSelectionLabel="true"
        noSelectionLabel="Empty"/>
    <s:convertEntity />
</h:selectOneMenu>t>
```

I also have a **Cancel** button on the modal panel:

```
<a4j:commandLink styleClass="btn-standard"
    immediate="true" 
    action="#{generalDialogAction.forwardCancelButton()}"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('modalPanel')}.hide(); Event.stop(event); return false;">
<span><h:outputText value="Cancel"></h:outputText></span>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Now field A and C are required fields. Is there a generic way in which a button (the `Cancel` button in this case) can check which input fields on a page are required, and if they are, clear their values when `Cancel` is clicked? Please help!

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? RichFaces 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: JSF 1.2, RichFaces 3.3.2

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, don't know from top of head.

Comment: It's my bad. I should probably mention that in every post. You seem to be an expert in JSF/RichFaces stuff :)!

Comment: JSF yes, RF only 4.0 (and not *that* expert, I used it since a month only). In RF 4.0 it would have been as simple as `<a4j:commandLink action="#{bean.cancel}" execute="@this" render="@form" />` where you null out the fields in `cancel()` method.

Comment: For RF 3.3 I think it's sufficient to use `immediate="true" reRender="theFormId"` (and null out the fields in the action method). Give it a try.

Comment: Does not work. I think I'll have to create a Java method that resets the values of each of the fields and call that method when Cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess... try,

```
<h:commandButton id="btnReset" value="Cancel" type="reset" />
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't reset the server side values. This only brings the form back to its initial state as it was after the last display/validation. I.e. it does effectively the same as `<input type="reset">`.

Comment: That would work for some scenario's but as BalusC said, I need to reset the server side values: callbackDialog.fieldA, callbackDialog.fieldB and callbackDialog.fieldC.

Comment: @TookTheRook : How did you reset the server side values? I am facing a similar problem.